# Method value is 'nil' rather than 'true' or 'false' after adding the field to a migration table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, schema.rb

I added a field called 'custom_design_enabled' to a 'members' table in my schema.rb file as a boolean with default true. When I attempt to change this in a rails console it says the field is 'nil' rather than either 'true' or 'false'. I think there is a part of the migration process that I have accidentally omitted which gives the method 'custom_design_enabled' a value. Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: can you share the migration file? you're not supposed to manipulate schema.rb yourself, it's done for you once you run the migration.

Comment: I'm a bit hesitant to share the whole file because I'm new to the company and not sure what I'm allowed to share but I ran "rails g migration add_custom_design_enabled_to_members custom_design_enabled:boolean" and that line was added to the "members" table in schema automatically, apologies for not conveying that properly. From the videos I've watched everything seemed to happen as it should and it mentioned that the value would be "nil" but never explained how to change it afterwards. Hope this has been more explanatory, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This is likely happening because you did not specify the default on the new field. The easiest way to fix this is to create a new migration. Create a new migration file (`rails g migration change_custom_design_enabled_default`) and try this in the migration file:

```
def up
  change_column :members, :custom_design_enabled, :boolean, default: true
end

def down
  change_column :members, :custom_design_enabled, :boolean, default: nil
end
```

Alternatively, you can try rolling back the last migration with `rake db:rollback` and add `null: false, default: true` to the original migration's `add_column` method. This might fail if the migration generated used `change` instead of `up` and `down` and rails can't figure out how to undo it, but it's worth a try.

Update: if rollback doesn't work, you can change the original migration to:

```
def up
  add_column :members, :custom_design_enabled, :boolean
end

def down
  remove_column :members, :custom_design_enabled
end
```

And do `rake db:rollback` afterwards.

Comment: The migration generated did use `change`, is there a similar solution with change substituted in for up/down? The following is the code in the migration file.

`def change
    add_column :members, :custom_design_enabled, :boolean
  end`

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes, you should also be able to do that. I edited my answer

Comment: I've tried a number of ways, including your suggestions, and I'm still where I started. Perhaps I'm doing something wrong but I'm fairly sure I copied them exactly.